# QoS not matching traffic

Tags: cisco, router, qos

My knowledge of QoS on Cisco is new as of yesterday and I have been trying to get a few different configurations on stack exchange that I found to work but the traffic only ever seems to match the default class and not my prioritised class. I may be missing something really obvious so would appreciate someone quickly checking over my configuration below.

This is on a Cisco 877 router.

```
class-map match-any RDP
  match access-group 145

policy-map RDP
  class RDP
  priority percent 70
  class class-default
  fair-queue
policy-map parent-policy
  class class-default
  shape average 458752
  service-policy RDP

int FastEthernet 0
  description WAN
  service-policy output parent-policy

int FastEthernet 1
  description LAN

access-list 145 permit ip any host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it's 877 you need to put QoS configuration on the VLAN interface (SVI), not physical FE ports. Also SVI doesn't support HQoS, so you'll need to simplify it for SVI.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have removed the parent policy and applied the RDP policy directly to the vlan interface however I am still not matching any packets.

Comment: Ok, I applied it on input instead of output and it's now picking up the packets. I need to play with the policies a bit as you said and will see where I am after that.